# Continuous convergence fails

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Given that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly and that $x_n \rightarrow x$, then I was wondering whether $d (f_n (x_n), f(x)) < \epsilon$, that is, does $f_n(x_n) $converge to$ f(x)$?

Any ideas? Been hitting myself with it. Note that we are NOT given that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Are the functions $f_n$ supposed to be continuous?  If they are, then $f$ will automatically be continuous.  If not, take $f_n = f$ where $f$ is some function discontinuous at $x$.

Comment: No, nothing is told about $f_n$, so we may not assume that. Would you mind elaborating on the example on how it satisfies the conditions?

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously false. Just take $$f_n(x)=f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x=0 \\ 0 & x \neq 0\end{cases}$$
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n}$$
$$x=0$$

Comment: I can follow why, but am struggling to write out exactly how you would show it does not converge pointwise

Comment: @user43901: The sequence $f_n(x_n)$ is $0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$. The value of $f(x)$ is $1$. This is about as easy a case of nonconvergence as it is possible to have.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I was thinking something else for $f_n(x_n)$ as having $1$ as one of the outputs. Nevermind. I t makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is copy-paste from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254511/elementary-question-about-uniform-convergence/254534?noredirect=1#comment714426_254534) where you asked for this counterexample.

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ on $[0,1]$ defined  by 
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1 \ \ , \ \ \ x=0\\ \\
\dfrac1n \ \ , \ \ \ x\in \left(0,1\right]{}\end{cases}.$$
The sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 \ \ , \ \ \ x=0\\ \\
0 \ \ , \ \ \ x\in \left(0,1\right]{}\end{cases}$$
and if $x_n=\dfrac1n$ (or any sequence on $[0,1]$ with $x_n\to0$ and $x_n\neq0 , \ \forall n\in\mathbb N$) then $x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ but $f_n(x_n)\not\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f(0).$

Comment: There was a temporal difference between your reply and my question, but thanks for pasting it anyway.